# HTML/CSS: no text change when hovering over a link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I want to create a hyperlink that doesn't change the text when I hover over it.
I've created a special style for that type of link as follows:

```
a.blank:hover{
    text-decoration:none;}
```

and the link itself:

```
<a class="blank" id="asdf">asdf</a>
```

I also have a general hyperlink style:

```
 a:hover, a:active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #321dd3; }
```

I know I could get around it by defining the text colour as being the same, but is there an umbrella method to force the hyperlink not to change anything?

Comment: its already working fine => http://jsfiddle.net/73yYs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are libraries such as [`reset.css`](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) (And [more](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/) [like](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) [it](http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/universal-selector-css-reset/)) that will remove these styles, but that may affect other parts of your page. It's best to use

```
a:hover, a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit; 
}
```

You will also need to add `a{text-decoration: none;}` and define the `color` property (That's what's `inherit`ed) for its parent element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VhCf8/

Comment: Thank you! color: inherit; was what I was looking for